# Why the parameter can't be passed properly when function called?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

```
var collection = {
    "5439": {
      "album": "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if(prop !== "tracks" && value !== ""){
    collection[id].prop=value;
  }
  return collection;
}
updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
```

why the result is `Object { album="ABBA Gold",  prop="ABBA"}`,not `Object { album="ABBA Gold",artist="ABBA"}`?
When to parse `collection[id].prop=value;` ,the value of prop is artist,the value of id is 5439,so `collection[id].prop=value;` should parsed into `collection[5439].artist="ABBA";`,why not？

Comment: Read the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [***`Bracket notation`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

> *An `object` property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation. **This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined** (when the property name is not determined until runtime).*

```
collection[id][prop] = value;
```

instead of,

```
collection[id].prop=value;
```

Comment: why `artist` the value of prop  can't be passed into the collection[id].prop,to make it be `collection[id]."artist"` ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: That is exactly what the bracket notation does: Dynamic property names. You are already using it that way for the `id`. Same thing applies to `prop`.

Comment: because how in the world is the parse supposed to know you mean a variable and not the string? That is how dot and bracket notation works.

Answer (score 0):

change the line `collection[id].prop=value;`

to `collection[id][prop]=value;`

```
var collection = {
  "5439": {
    "album": "ABBA Gold"
  }
};

function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if (prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }
  return collection;
}
updateRecords(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
```